# Live dashboard using actoncable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm trying to build a live updating dashboard in rails 5 with a actioncable. I was searching for some example which might guide me into implementing this but all i found was some chatting apps. I'm planning to use [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/). How would i be create an polling Channel which will an API will get data from server and display in my app. Because chat app are calling when user send a message. I want to make it automate polling every X seconds. Any links or reference will be quite helpful. Thanks!!!

Comment: Isn't chat guide helpful at all? It shows you how to create a channel, set up a queue, subscribe to it and lastly broadcasting. That should pretty much help you with your dashboard app!

Comment: Hey ,thanks i figured out with broadcast. I added after_create_commit ApplicationJob and that was it. That's for the info.